# WiFi automatically toggles off after turning it on

Tags: wi-fi

In the mobile set, the charging is almost full, rest of the applications are working well. WiFi stopped working abruptly. After switching WiFi ON  from "Settings" it automatically turns off in 5 secs. 
I have Restarted the mobile and checked again. But the problem is still there.

Comment: you need to provide more information. what kind of device do you have? which android version? is it rooted? do you have a custom rom? do you know how to take logs via adb?

Comment: Are you rooted... If so do you have tasker? Do you have custom ROM? Or have you installed some Xposed  modules/framework???

Comment: Hi! 1) Since when did this problem start? 2) Did you install something on your device and then notice this behavior?  3) As asked above, which Android device and version are you using, and is the device rooted? 4) You may try clearing data from **Settings -> all apps -> Settings -> clear data, clear cache**, restart and see if the issue persist. 5) You may also try a factory reset if nothing helps.